# Trouble connecting to MySQL through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to connect to my database I am presented with two errors:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local
>   MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established

These have only arisen since I took the connection code, placed it in an external file and called it at the top of my script with `include('connect.php')`.

Here's my code:

```
$dbhost = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "xxx";

$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

The line that flags up the error is:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (product_url, shop_name, photo_url, was_price, now_price) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: you're using mysqli and then use mysql to query

Comment: First obvious thing I see that you're creating a `mysqli` connection, but then running a `mysql` query. mysql is dangerous and deprecated, btw. mysqli or pdo are the newer accepted standards

Comment: @Ronnie nice catch, wouldn't have seen that one

Comment: Schoolboy error! Thanks guys. I've been shockingly slow to adopt `mysqli` so still getting to grips with it.

Comment: We've all made mistakes like this lol. Also, I suggest PDO rather than mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Do write it up as an answer and I'll accept. No doubt it'll save the next sucker some time!

Comment: Here is a link to a nice PDO tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, what are the main advantages of PDO over mysqli?

Comment: The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) shows you the differences in API between PDO and MySQLi